# smartEDA - Assign unique color to target categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was exploring the capabilities of the smartEDA package and stuck with a challenge. The target column "US" has 2 categories - "Yes" and "No". The output *(below)* shows the same colour for 2 categories compared to having 2 different colours.

For instance, "Yes" - blue / "No" - red

[image]

Here's the sample code.

```
#install.packages("ISLR")
library("ISLR")
#install.packages("SmartEDA")
library("SmartEDA")

plot31 <- ExpNumViz(Carseats,target="US",nlim=4,scatter=TRUE,fname=NULL)
plot31[[1]]
```

I explored the arguments from the `ExpNumViz` function by adding the `col` parameter (*documentation: define the fill colour for box plot. Number of color should be equal to number of categories in target variable*)

```
plot31 <- ExpNumViz(col = 2, Carseats,target="US",nlim=4,scatter=TRUE,fname=NULL) #assuming 2 categories
```

However, I received the following error

```
Error in `f()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the color names in col parameter. The number of color names elements must match the number of categories ploted.

```
    plot31 <- ExpNumViz(Carseats,
                        target="US",
                        nlim=4,
                        scatter=TRUE,
                        fname=NULL,
                        col = c("Red", "Blue"))

    plot31[[1]]
```

[image: Output]